# How to test a child component from parent component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, unit-testing

I have one component file look like following and I would like to write a unit test that subComponent should display if `subComponent` is passed as prop for `Header`
 under `App.test.tsx` from `Header` parent component. I know I can write a test by just rendering the Header component and pass sub as prop. but how can I test the same functionality by rendering the App component?

```
// SubComponentButton.test.tsx
const sub = <button test-id="test-id">Mock Sub Component</button>;

render(<Header subComponent={sub} />
expect(screen.queryByRole('button', {name: /mock sub/i})).toHaveTextContenet('Mock Sub Component');

// App component
export default function App() {
    const subComponent: JSX.Element = useMemo(() => {
        return ( <SubComponentButton />);
    }, []);

     return (
       <div className="App">
       <Header
         subComponent={subComponent}
       />
       </div>
     );
}
```

Comment: what are you using to write you other unit tests? this information can hel provide a more concise anwer

Comment: jest and test-library

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could create a file dedicated to the test, for example `Header.spec.tsx`, better if placed in a folder called maybe `tests` or `__tests__`. After that you can run jest to test your component, I think `yarn test` or `npm test` should work.

Try in this way:

```
describe("Header", () => {
  it("renders the subComponent when provided", () => {
    const sub = <button datatest-id="test-id">Mock Sub Component</button>;
    render(<Header subComponent={sub} />)
    
    expect(screen.getByTestId('test-id')).toBeInTheDocument();
  })
})
```

In this way you are assuming that in the dom will be displayed the component passed as subComponent

To test it from the App component you can do something like this:

*App.tsx*

```
export default function App() {
  const subComponent: JSX.Element = useMemo(() => {
    return ( <SubComponentButton />);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header subComponent={subComponent} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

*SubComponentButton.tsx*

```
export default function SubComponentButton() {
  return (
    <button data-testid="sub-component-button">SubComponent</button>
  );
}
```

*App.spec.tsx*

```
describe("App", () => {
  it("renders the subComponent", () => {
    render(<App />)
    
    // You can test by id (as you can see the SubComponentButton contains a button with a test-id attribute)
    expect(screen.getByTestId('sub-component-button')).toBeInTheDocument();

    // You can test by role
    expect(screen.getByRole('button', { name: "SubComponent" })).toBeInTheDocument();
  })
})
```

Comment: yap, i know exactly how I can test under `Header.test.tsx` but my question is how to test `header` under `App.test.tsx` from parent component to test child component

Comment: thank you, possible to know how to verify `SubComponent` must be under `Header` div? if if have class of div `header` under Header component

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @jacobcan118